# Query google app engine datastore for all entities

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Given this model class

```
class Student(ndb.Model):
   student_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
   student_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
   score=ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)

   def toJSON(self):
        jsonData = {
        "Student Id":str(self.student_id),
        "Name":self.student_name,
        "Score": str(self.score)
        }
        return json.encode(jsonData)
```

I am trying to run a query to return all the student names, along with the score for each student in JSON format.

I already ran a query on the datastore and was able to retrieve information regarding each student using

```
class ViewStudentDetailsHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    student_id=self.request.get('id')
    callback = self.request.get('callback')
    student = Student.get_by_id(student_id)
    if student:
        if (callback):
            self.response.write(callback + '(' + student.toJSON() + ')')
        else:
            self.response.write(student.toJSON())
    else:
        if(callback):
            self.response.write(callback + "(null)")
        else:
            self.response.write("No student with that id")
```

But have no clue how to get  `ALL` of the students.I have read [examples](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) given by Google, but am still lost.I know this time around i'll need a loop, but that's about all i can come up with.Any ideas would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to perform a query, and depending how many entities returning all them in a single request will either not be possible or practical.  You will then need to use cursors with the query.

You should read the section of Queries in the ndb docs - they are clear about what needs to be done -  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries

A simple query for all items and to return the details you want as a list of Json records you would do the following, using the map method of a query, which calls the supplied function or classmethod.  It doesn't expect a method of the entity thats why I don't use toJSON directly.

```
def callback(student):
    return student.toJSON())

results = Student.query().map(callback)
```

You may need to fiddle with your toJSON method, have a look at what results looks like when you run it.  `results` may also need to explicitly converted to json, so you may want to defer the explicit json.encode till after after you have run the query.